# Build android open source project

Tags: android

I try to build FBReader project(http://code.google.com/p/fbreaderplus/source/checkout). How to add libraries which described in README.build? When I make project with cygwin got such messages:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrar
y/text/src/model'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrary
/text/src/model'
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrar
y/text/src/area'
Compiling ZLTextParagraphBuilder.o ...In file included from ZLTextParagraphBuild
er.cpp:30:0:
ZLTextParagraphBuilder.h:26:29: fatal error: fribidi/fribidi.h: No such file or
directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrary/text/../../makefiles/subdir
.mk:14: recipe for target `ZLTextParagraphBuilder.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ZLTextParagraphBuilder.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrary
/text/src/area'
Makefile:25: recipe for target `.objects' failed
make[1]: *** [.objects] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Argentum/Desktop/fbreader/zlibrary
/text'
Makefile:9: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This error `ZLTextParagraphBuilder.h:26:29: fatal error: fribidi/fribidi.h: No such file or
directory` tells you that it's missing fribidi, http://www.fribidi.org/

I don't know how you could get past the configure stage -- isn't it supposed to check the presence of libraries?

Anyway install fribidi and try again.

HTH